# How to get specific cookie value in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I can now display the all cookie using `socket.request.headers.cookie`.

When I console the output is like this

```
PHPSESSID=mtklg8k81cpkop5ug6aechbb34; user=77; io=1Klg6xgTRXhb2OWiAAAA
```

How can I get only the user value which is 77? Code below give me an error undefined

```
var cookief = socket.request.headers.cookie;
console.log(cookief['user']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the cookies into their separate cookies and properties.  The usual module to use for that is [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser).

For use with socket.io, you can use a small wrapper with it for use with socket.io called [socket.io-cookie-parser](https://github.com/mhuggins/socket.io-cookie-parser).

```
const cookieParser = require('socket.io-cookie-parser');
io.use(cookieParser());

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // access socket.request.cookies
    console.log(socket.request.cookies['user'];
});
```

Comment: Can this be used on the clientside sir?