# How do I send data from my route handler to my socket.io function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

How do I send data from my route handler to my socket.io function? My code is as follows:

```js
// Game
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    const currentUser = cookies['current_user'];
    const roomName = cookies['room_name'];

    if (roomName) {
        res.render('pages/game', {
            room: roomName
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

io.of('/game').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.join(roomName);

    io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);
    (async() => {
        const sockets = await io.of('/game').in(roomName).fetchSockets();
        console.log(sockets.length);
    })();
});
```

I would like the socket to join the room defined in the cookie in the route handler above, but I'm not sure how to get the room name into the socket.io function. I considered putting the socket.io stuff in a function and then passing the data as a parameter, but that would cause the same problem as just putting the socket.io stuff inside the route handler, which as I have learnt from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31924051) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31923483) is not the right way to do things. Global variables also don't sound like a good idea - multiple users joining would interfere with each other's data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use the cookie from socket.handshake.headers.cookie and get the same roomname which is used in your route as both will have access for same cookie at a time

Comment: @RajeshVerma I don't quite understand. How should I implement this into my code? Do I need to put ` socket.handshake.headers.cookie` in my socket.io function somewhere?

Comment: there are many ways for same see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359467/how-to-get-specific-cookie-value-in-socket-io

Comment: How would I set the cookie inside the route handler though?

Comment: what @RajeshVerma means is that you can use socket.handshake.headers.cookie inside your socket.io event listeners instead of req.cookies inside the express event listeners. You don't really have to do much else to implement it.

Comment: @Anvay if you get the req.cookies inside the socket io function, thats good.

Comment: @RajeshVerma but won't socket.handshake.headers.cookie have the same content as req.cookies? What do you mean by thats good?

Comment: Actually I dont this req.cookies will help in this case as room was alreadly visible in router function and need to pass the same in socket io. So, we need to access the room cookie into the io function.

Comment: @RajeshVerma he can just import the cookie library and use `const cookies = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie || "");`. Then, the cookies variable will be an object containing all the cookies of the user with that specific socket. you can do this in the connection event listener.

Comment: @Anvay Thanks for clearing up the confusion - using `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` inside the function worked perfectly. Quick question, though: what's the difference between `cookieParser` and `cookie`? I replaced `cookieParser` at first, but then cookies didn't work at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what the real reason is, but the library for cookie parser is 7 years old, and apparently sends the cookie information to `socket.request.cookies`. However, I would still use the cookie library because it is being actively updated, unlike the cookieParser library.

Comment: I will write an answer so that anyone who comes here can see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the user's cookies by using the `socket.handshakes.headers.cookie` string. Since this is not an object because it is a header, you need to use the `cookie` library to convert it into an object.

This is the code that you can use:
`const cookies = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie);`

### Important!

I suggest that you do not use the `socket.io-cookie-parser` library because has not been updated since 2014 (7 years ago in 2021). However, if you do decide to use it, you must include `io.use(cookieParser());` at the top of your code and you can access the cookies from `socket.request.cookies` or `socket.request.signedCookies` if using a secret. Please go to the [documentation](https://github.com/mhuggins/socket.io-cookie-parser#readme) for more information.